# Metric space inequality

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given $$d(x,y)=2^{-max\{m \in \mathbb{N} : 2^{m} divides (x-y)\} }$$ for $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ for $x=y$, how can I prove that $$d(x,y)\leq max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}, x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$$ I think it should be trivial, something related to the triangle inequality, but I really don't know how to begin. I've tried assuming (without loss of generality) that $x>y>z$ and constructing from there, but to no avail. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Note that for any integers $u$ and $v$ we have

$$2^{-\max\{m\in\Bbb N:2^m\mid u\}}\le 2^{-\max\{m\in\Bbb N:2^m\mid v\}}$$

if and only if

$$\max\{m\in\Bbb N:2^m\mid u\}\ge\max\{m\in\Bbb N:2^m\mid v\}\;.$$

- Explain why this means that in order to show that $d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$, you need only show that if $2^m\mid x-z$ and $2^m\mid z-y$, then $2^m\mid x-y$.
- Show that if $2^m\mid x-z$ and $2^m\mid z-y$, then $2^m\mid x-y$.